# How Can I Fix System.Net.Mail.SmtpException

Tags: c#, smtp, smtpclient, mailmessage

[This is Image Of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFW81.png)Here is Full Problem System.Net.Mail.SmtpException: 'The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required.

```
    `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from.Text, to.Text, subject.Text, body.Text);

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtp.Text, 587);

        client.Port = 587;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username.Text, password.Text);

        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(mail);
        MessageBox.Show("Mail Sent!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }`
```

Here is The Code and I tried al Thing please tell How can I Fix it Email Sender

Comment: Note that `EnableSsl` enables STARTTLS, so the client connects over an unencrypted channel and then sends a command to enable encryption. Perhaps the server is expecting you to open an actual encrypted connection on port 587, rather than using STARTTLS? Maybe there's a different port you can connect to which allows STARTTLS (465? even 25?). If not, you might have to use an SMTP client which supports starting off with an encrypted connection, such as MailKit.

Comment: Which server exactly are you connecting to? Gmail/Outlook/etc? We can check their docs, see what they're expecting.

Comment: See in the Docs the Remarks section of [SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient). The official documentation itself suggests not to use this class anymore, also pointing to a possible replacement. One of the reasons is explained in the first comment.

Comment: @canton7 I am Connecting To Gmail

Comment: @canton7 Please Tell How can I fix it By Code

Comment: OK, port 587 is the STARTTLS port for Gmail, so it's not that. Are you using an App Password?

Answer (score 0):

Because you use custom credentials and use authentication (enablessl = true). Together with your own login (not default) you need to add:

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
```

before setting client.credentials

Otherwise the credentials you filled in won't be used

EDIT:
when this line is added as stated before, and there are still authentication problems. Try checking if all of the variables are correct. This can be done using the website: https://www.smtper.net/

Technically the variables should be tested before you start programming.

The error you are getting 'The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required.' means that you aren't using HTTPS and/or can't authenticate using the credentials. smtper.net is therefor the best tool of finding out if your credentials are correct.

Your code seems to be correct on first glance with the exception of adding client.usedeafultcredentials = false. Wich is why I'm assuming the variables you are working with are incorrect.

Comment: It Didn't work I used it Before But not Working

Comment: Can you confirm the SMTP server is set up correctly using this url? https://www.smtper.net/

If you can send the mail with this, the problem is your code. If not, the problem is with the smtp server

Comment: `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage mail = new MailMessage(from.Text, to.Text, subject.Text, body.Text);

        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(smtp.Text, 587);

        client.Port = 587;
        client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(username.Text, password.Text);

        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(mail);
        MessageBox.Show("Mail Sent!", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }`

Comment: This Is My Full Code

Comment: SMTP Server is Of Gmail smtp.gmail.com

Comment: Did you try to send the mail using smtper.net?

Comment: Actually send me code what are you saying I am Begineer so Please I will try it for sure

Comment: Check edit. your code seems to be correct